# What is the difference between language of thought is innate(known as mentalese) and natural 'learned' language?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, philosophy-of-language, linguistics

Language of thought theories generally fall into two categories. The first one is accept the innate, known as mentalese and the second one is which don't accept the innate, but the language of thought is natural learned language. I want more clarification about their ideas and differences particularly these two categories.

Comment: This seems like it's a core concept in linguistics and a philosophical question. You might get helpful answers by posting it to linguistics.SE as well as here.

Comment: For philosophy.se, this seems like it might be a borderline definition question (definition questions are in general off-topic).

Comment: You can see [The Language of Thought Hypothesis](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/language-thought/).